# Is it possible to set selection in Quill RTE using pixel positions?

Tags: quill

Quill has a [`getBounds`](https://quilljs.com/docs/api/#getbounds) API that allows you to get the pixel position of a selection. Is it possible to do the reverse calculation, i.e. getting a selection from a pixel position?

I want to use that information to be able to [`setSelection`](https://quilljs.com/docs/api/#setselection) knowing only the desired pixel position of that selection.

Comment: There is no API for this at the moment. Feel free to submit a feature request for this API: https://github.com/quilljs/quill/blob/develop/.github/CONTRIBUTING.md#feature-requests. If your use case is generalizable and useful for others it may be added.

Comment: Thanks @jhchen. I've created a feature request now: https://github.com/quilljs/quill/issues/1415